# compiling objective-c code for ios app on Windows

Tags: objective-c, windows, gnustep

I know objective-c code can be compilied on Windows by [gnuStep](http://www.gnustep.org/experience/Windows.html).  GnuStep clone most of the apple libraries but not all. So I am looking smart way find the remaining class since I assume using apple library on other os might be against the apple's licence.(Please don't aswer saying buy mac or wmvare solutions).
Thanks.

Comment: i always thought there was no way to compile obj-c code on any other platform then osx.  i guess i need to investigate gnuStep!

Comment: Can you be more precise on what is missing in gnustep?

Answer (score 1):

For iOS you depend on apple's frameworks (Cocoa Touch et al). They are only available on Mac OS X.

While it is possible, to run OS X on PCs (search for "Hackingtosh"), apple forbids to run it on non-apple hardware in its EULA.

Comment: I know it may be against the apple's licence. but there are several apps like Adobe-flex have accoplish this goal.

Comment: @Mobinex what do you mean by "accomplish this goal", do you mean being cross platform compatible? Because if this is what you want you are not choosing the easiest path.